# Scaled down image is not anti-aliased in Firefox, IE9, and Opera, but it is in Chrome and Safari

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, firefox, opera

https://i.stack.imgur.com/xeVRb.png

Chrome and Safari renders a scaled down image nicely, but doesn't on Firefox, IE9, or Opera. How would I anti-alias the image on browsers that don't do it automatically?

Comment: I don't think this ability exists. You're basically just seeing an instance where the Webkit rendering engine is better than the others.

Answer (score 0):

Your only option would be to load the image into a canvas and down-sample it yourself, onto a new, smaller canvas. This will limit you to same-origin images, however.

On the other hand, you should ask yourself whether the effort is worth it? The users of these browsers cope fine with this for thousands of other sites, so why should you need to do anything different?